# Windows 7 App Database Location

Tags: database, windows-7

Our application is targeted at Windows 7.  It is a database winforms application.  We would like it to be Windows 7 Logo compliant.  Our question is where to locate the user database.  It must be accessible to all users and of course have read/write capability.  We do not want to modify permissions during installation.  The Windows 7 Logo compliance rules don't address all user data locations.  This is not simple program data like settings.  I'm sure many of you have had this problem. Where have you located the database?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData

Comment: This folder does not have write permission for all users by default.